# Minified ASPX with no white space, but in browser displays fully indented and formatted

Tags: c#, asp.net, whitespace

I have minified my aspx pages with an external application that simply removes white space. I am not doing this on the fly at compile/runtime. Clearly my pages are minified as I can open them up in a text editor and there is no white space and the file size is dramatically smaller.

I upload it to the server, yet no matter what browser I display in, the source code appears formatted exactly is it did before. What would be the reason for this? of course I have cleared cache. It is almost like google pre formats your source code for readability but I have seen other websites that can achieve the desired result..and google.com is clearly all dried up of whitespace

Thoughts?

Comment: Sample ASPX + corresponding HTML output (4-5 lines)  will likely help to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you checking for the layout?

Most modern browsers have built in "Pretty Print" formatting by default, especially if you use any of the built in tools / inspectors.

In order to check that the download content really contains, use a tool like Fiddler or something similar and and then take a look at the response using the *Raw* or *HexView* tabs to get and idea of what's actually been sent down to the browser in terms of bytes.

If you're aren't seeing lots of spacing (in raw view) or 20 or 09 in hex view then you're not sending the whitespace and its the browser trying to be helpful.

Comment: Great Response, I have obtained 'Fiddler' and it certainly seems my output HTML has LOTS of whitespace and is formatted nicely and pretty. My raw ASPX files dont have a white space to be seen, what does this mean?

Comment: If you can remove the APAX page from the server and request it again - you should get a 404. If not then you're not deploying what you think you are. Are you pre-compiling the site or using a folder xcopy type deployment?   Did you remove the white-space before compiling and deploying or after?